# Отключение перетаскивания метки

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Всем привет!
Необходим функционал включения/отключения режима перетаскивания метки на карте. Включение у меня получилось сделать, а вот отключение не работает:

```js
function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [37.626, 55.750625],
    zoom: 7,
    controls: []
  }, {
    buttonMaxWidth: 300
  });

  var point = new ymaps.Placemark([37.509155, 55.802052], {
    balloonContent: 'Точка'
  }, {
    preset: 'islands#blueDotIcon'
  });
  myMap.geoObjects.add(point);

  $('.drag').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      point.options.set('draggable', 'true');
    } else {
      point.options.set('draggable', 'false');
    }
  });
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="drag">Draggable</label>
```

Подскажите, как можно реализовать отключение перетаскивания метки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы устанавливаете в свойство 'draggable' true/false строкой (которая в javascript, если она не пустая, всегда воспринимается как true), когда как параметру необходим булевый тип. Немного поправил ваш пример:

```js
function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [37.626, 55.750625],
    zoom: 7,
    controls: []
  }, {
    buttonMaxWidth: 300
  });

  var point = new ymaps.Placemark([37.509155, 55.802052], {
    balloonContent: 'Точка'
  }, {
    preset: 'islands#blueDotIcon'
  });
  myMap.geoObjects.add(point);

  $('.drag').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      point.options.set('draggable', true);
    } else {
      point.options.set('draggable', false);
    }
  });
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="drag">Draggable</label>
```